# Putting SVG in PDF with FOP works on Local Machine but not on Server

Tags: apache-fop

On the local machine everything works fine, when I try to run it on the server I get this error, it generates fine, but without the SVG logo included.

2019-07-12 09:09:01,956 [ERROR] [main] [LoggingEventListener] Image not available. URI: (instream-object). Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for null (No context info available)
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for null
at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:181)
at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingDocument(AbstractIFPainter.java:317)
at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:286)

**Here is how it is included**

```
<fo:block margin-right="1.5cm" text-align="right">
         <fo:instream-foreign-object>
              #include("Logo.vm")
         </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

**Here is the SVG Include File snippet Logo.vm:**

```
<svg
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
        version="1.0"
        id="Ebene_1"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 175 40"
        enable-background="new 0 0 115 40"
        xml:space="preserve"
        inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
        width="146"
        height="38"
        sodipodi:docname="DL_115x40.svg"><metadata
     id="metadata3067"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
        rdf:resource="http://purl.org/d/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
        id="defs3065" /><sodipodi:namedview
        pagecolor="#ffffff"
        bordercolor="#666666"
        borderopacity="1"
        objecttolerance="10"
        gridtolerance="10"
        guidetolerance="10"
        inkscape:pageopacity="0"
        inkscape:pageshadow="2"
        inkscape:window-width="492"
        inkscape:window-height="309"
        id="namedview3063"
        showgrid="false"
        inkscape:zoom="2.7826087"
        inkscape:cx="57.5"
        inkscape:cy="20"
        inkscape:window-x="0"
        inkscape:window-y="25"
        inkscape:window-maximized="0"
        inkscape:current-layer="Ebene_1" />
    <path class="st0" d="M122.9 34.2c0 .8-.6 1.3-1 .... *MORE AND MORE NUMBERS COMMING*
```

Comment: Is the SVG itself inside instream-foreign-object or is it an external graphic?

Comment: It is <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                        #include("shipLogoMW.vm")
                                    </fo:instream-foreign-object>

Comment: And this URL can also be reached from server, so that is fine: http://purl.org/d/dcmitype/StillImage

Comment: possibly a mimetype issue? I do not know what  #include("shipLogoMW.vm") means but I assume it gets the SVG file and puts it into the tag. Maybe because the file is named .vm and not .svg the server is not returning the correct mimetype?

Comment: We tried this as well, but did not work. Also, we tried to include it as external graphic, but same issue here. The strange thing is, that we have similar code on another production server and it runs there. Maybe it is some kind of pom problem, I am not sure. Batik is loaded.  Also for Batik it was mentioned to run JAVA with -Djava.awt.headless=true, but this didn't make a difference as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occurred when using Amazon Corretto JDK. Java Corretto has some bug that causes issues with fonts, see issues on the Github: [Broken Font support (Fontconfig) in AWS-Lambda (java11)](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/118) and [Generic Linux distro requires Fontconfig for font support (java8)](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/64)

What actually solved this issue for us was installing package `fontconfig` on the OS (we are running Ubuntu virtual servers, so no problem with that):

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
```

After that SVG renderring was OK.